# How to order by string by Month name using javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a string `"APRIL,AUGUST,JULY,JUNE,MAY"`. I want to order it by month name.
The required output is `APRIL,MAY,JUNE,JULY,AUGUST`.

Comment: 1. Split the string by `","`. 2. Order the obtained array. 3. Join it by `","`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep order list of all months and do the sorting based on that:

```js
const order = ["JANUARY", "FEBRUARY", "MARCH", "APRIL", "MAY", "JUNE", "JULY", "AUGUST", "SEPTEMBER", "OCTOBER", "NOVEMBER", "DECEMBER"];

const sort = (data) =>
  data
.split(',')
.sort((a, b) => order.indexOf(a) - order.indexOf(b))
.join()

const data1 = 'APRIL,AUGUST,JULY,JUNE,MAY'
console.log(sort(data1))

const data2 = 'APRIL,AUGUST,JULY,JUNE,MAY,APRIL'
console.log(sort(data2))
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is probably:

```
const s = "APRIL,AUGUST,JULY,JUNE,MAY";
const months = ["JANUARY", "FEBRUARY", "MARCH", "APRIL", "MAY", "JUNE", "JULY", "OCTOBER", "SEPTEMBER", "NOVEMBER", "DECEMBER"]
let resultArray = [];

months.forEach(month => {
    if (s.includes(month)) {
        resultArray.push(month);
    }
})

console.log(resultArray.join(','));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Array#filter() on preordered array and check if each name exists in the string

```js
const s = "APRIL,AUGUST,JULY,JUNE,MAY";
const months = ["JANUARY", "FEBRUARY", "MARCH", "APRIL", "MAY", "JUNE", "JULY", "OCTOBER", "SEPTEMBER", "NOVEMBER", "DECEMBER"]

const res = months.filter(m => s.includes(m)).join()

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

The other solutions might be inefficient because they rely on the String.includes or Array.indexOf prototypes, which cost alone O(n) (where n is the length of the input string).
I propose an alternative solution that uses a dictionary, which supports indexing in amortized `O(1)` time.
The overall time complexity is `O(m logm)`, where `m` is the number of months in the `input` string.

You can index month names in `monthNamesObj` in amortized O(1) time.

```js
  const input = "APRIL,AUGUST,JULY,JUNE,MAY";

  // inputMonthNames = ['APRIL', 'AUGUST', 'JULY', 'JUNE', 'MAY']
  const inputMonthNames = input.split(',');

  // dictionary that maps month names to the correspective order index
  const monthNamesObj = {
    'JANUARY': 0,
    'FEBRUARY': 1,
    'MARCH': 2,
    'APRIL': 3,
    'MAY': 4,
    'JUNE': 5,
    'JULY': 6,
    'AUGUST': 7,
    'SEPTEMBER': 8,
    'OCTOBER': 9,
    'NOVEMBER': 10,
    'DECEMBER': 11,
  };

  // sort the input month names according to their numeric order
  const orderedMonths = inputMonthNames.sort((a, b) => monthNamesObj[a] - monthNamesObj[b]);

  // APRIL,MAY,JUNE,JULY,AUGUST
  console.log(orderedMonths.join(','));
```